# using datagridview for update and delete data

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have some question about `DataGridView`.

1. I can show table in `DataGridView`, but I don't know that after update data in DataGridView how can I update that fields in table?
2. how can I delete selected rows in `DataGridView` and table in SQL Server?
3. I don't want to let user insert data with using `DataGridView`.
4. If I want to let to user to insert new row what can I do?
5. How I can change table's column name in `DataGridView` for display to the user? (i.e. the column name is "user" but I want to show that like "name")

Comment: I found answer for question 5:I use this code : dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "name";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "family";

Comment: I reformatted your original question text a little so it displays nicer. Perhaps have a look at the [Markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how this works!

Comment: excuse me,isn't my question clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a website that might help:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/datagrid/article.php/c13041

What you can also do is just search on google:
Datagridview select add delete update